# Access Object by a dynamic key

Tags: r

Is there any way to place `res` inside of the SMOTE function, like res is always a changeable column name, think as it is a function parameter

```
res <- "Class"
newdata <- DMwR::SMOTE(res ~ .,data, 
                         perc.over  = 150, 
                         perc.under = 150)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are fancier ways to edit formulas, but the one I can always remember is as a character string,

```
res <- "Class"
my_formula <- as.formula(paste0(res, " ~ ."))
newdata <- DMwR::SMOTE(my_formula, 
                         perc.over  = 150, 
                         perc.under = 150)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `reformulate`

```
DMwR::SMOTE(reformulate(".", res), data,  perc.over  = 150, 
                     perc.under = 150)
```

Using a reproducible example

```
data(iris)
reformulate(".", response = 'Species')
#Species ~ .

DMwR::SMOTE( reformulate(".", response = 'Species'), data = iris, perc.over  = 150, 
                     perc.under = 150)
```

-output

```
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#56        5.700000    2.800000     4.500000   1.3000000 versicolor
#132       7.900000    3.800000     6.400000   2.0000000  virginica
#68        5.800000    2.700000     4.100000   1.0000000 versicolor
#120       6.000000    2.200000     5.000000   1.5000000  virginica
#119       7.700000    2.600000     6.900000   2.3000000  virginica
#131       7.400000    2.800000     6.100000   1.9000000  virginica
#90        5.500000    2.500000     4.000000   1.3000000 versicolor
# ..
```